# Openvpn static route / force GW

Tags: openvpn

so i have in setup, one openvpn server running on 192.168.7.0/24 subnet.
the openvpn server is serving a semi comlex setup of servers, so changing the subnet is only seen as a last resort ( i hope i dont get there though)

the problem is, some users are complaining that in homeoffice, they cant use some network resources although they have the vpn on, a deeper look showed that they use for their home networks the same subnet as for the openvpn server! thus requests are being internaly routed instead of being sent via the VPN.

changing to IPv6 is not possible, and using NATing for such a thing is extrtemly dirty.

i tried force the vpn clients to use the vpn server as default GW with
push "redirect-gateway def1"
or/and
push "redirect-gateway local def1"
on the server config side, with no luck

any ideas?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the gateway redirect that in the routing table the more specific entries override the less specific ones. So pushing the gateway usually not a big help, since every computer contains a `/24` link-scope route entry for the local network, which is of course more specific than the advertised default route, so it will be used instead.

If you really don't want to change the VPN subnet, then the best you can do is push specific routes for the resources on the VPN network, since a route for a simple host will override the link-scope entry.

You might want to "cheat", and send two `/25` networks (that is, `192.168.7.0/25` and `192.168.7.128/25`), which are more specific than the local `/24` network, and these two covers almost the full VPN subnet (minus the hosts on the "border" -- that is, hosts `127` and `128`). In this case you want to push the `redirect-local` or `redirect-local def1` directives as well, to make sure not to lose the default gateway, and with it, the client's connection to the VPN server.

The best solution, however, in my opinion, is to change the VPN subnet to something "ugly" which is unlikely to collide with home networks (for example, quite a few people sets their home network to something like `10.287.29.0/24`). This might be a daunting task, but it is the "clean" way. Also, it is the best way to actually make sure you won't encounter surprises because of overlapping subnets.

Comment: thanks for the hint! i will work on it and keep you informed. pushing a /28 route should be enough since i have 12 hosts there

Comment: For 12 hosts, I don't think you even need a subnet to be advertised, you can simply push the 12 static routes. This is a cleaner solution, and 12 routes aren't that much.